# How to forward a non-movable object in std::pair

Tags: c++

I can't figure out the syntax to perfectly forward a `std::pair` when it contains something that's non-movable.

```
#include <mutex>
#include <list>
#include <utility>

struct A
{
    A(int x)
    {

    }
};

int main()
{
    std::list<std::pair<std::mutex, std::mutex>> v;
    v.emplace_back(); // ok

    std::list<std::pair<A, A>> v2;
    v2.emplace_back(3, 4); // ok

    std::list<std::pair<A, std::mutex>> v3;
    v3.emplace_back(3, std::forward<std::mutex>(std::mutex{})); // help
}
```

Comment: You’re gonna want to make that mutex a ptr or a reference to a mutex

Comment: Note: the list interaction is superfluous for reproduction. Just constructing a `std::make_pair<A,std::mutex>(3, std::mutex{});` will also exhibit.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You must construct the `std::mutex` in-place from an empty argument list. This can be done using the `std::piecewise_construct` constructor, which allows you to forward arguments for the constructors of the two elements as `std::tuple`s.

```
// for std::forward_as_tuple
#include<tuple>

// ...

v3.emplace_back(std::piecewise_construct, std::forward_as_tuple(3), std::forward_as_tuple());
```